# Arcpy - Python script select many values from attribute table raster

Tags: arcpy, python

I run this simple script, line-by-line, and I get the error

> Runtime error SyntaxError: can't assign to literal (, line 1)

What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
# Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/pro-restaura/ProRestaura-dados/outout-mg/reproject-mg"

# Set local variables
in_features = (arcpy.Raster, "area_pro_restaura_minas.tif")
out_feature_class = "D:/pro-restaura/ProRestaura-dados/outout-mg/reproject-mg/class_UpVeg.tif"
where_clause = "Value" = 2103

# Execute Select
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features, out_feature_class, where_clause)
```

Comment: A syntax error is a syntax error. You've attempted to assign the integer value 2103 to the string constant "Value". String literals with quotes in them need to be quoted: `where_clause = '"Value" = 2103'`

Comment: @Vince although there is a syntax error, it will not work after fixing the expression because the OP uses a tool designed for vector data not for raster data.

Comment: Yes, and there's a third error, not mentioned in the question and only reflected in comments, trying to use the equivalence operator with a list of terms.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Extract by Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-attributes.htm) function if you have Spatial Analyst to extract specific values from raster data:

Here is a code snippet from the help above:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Import Spatial Analyst extension
from arcpy.sa import *

# Specify the workspace
env.workspace = r"F:\Ahmad\Test\ASTGTM2_N22E093"

# Use the extract function. "test_dem" is the name of the raster file
# with esri grid format
# If you want to extract multiple values at once, you have to write
# it like this: "VALUE in (500,1000,1500)"
attExtract = ExtractByAttributes("test_dem", "VALUE in(500,1000,1500)")

# Save the output raster file. No extension means esro grid as input file
attExtract.save(r"F:\Ahmad\Test\ASTGTM2_N22E093\test_dem_2")
```

You need to adapt your code based on the code above.

This the attribute table of the input raster `"test_dem"`:

[image]

The attribute table of the output raster `"test_dem_2"`:

[image]

Here is how it looks in the table of content:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. 
I don't want to do spatial analys, I just want to select in the attribute table by value.
 "where_clause = ' "Value" = ('2103', '2109', '1405', 2103') '

Comment: `arcpy.Select_analysis` deals only with vector data. If you need to extract values from raster data, you need to use `arcpy.sa.ExtractByAttributes()`. To use the function, you need to have Spatial Analyst extension.

Comment: Thank you very much to try to help me!

I made changes to the methods and the declaration form of the string (Value) and integer values (2103, 2109), but doesnt seems to work 
Here it is:
`import arcpy
from arcpy import env
 
env.workspace = "D: \ pro-restore \ pro-data-outout-mg \ reproject-mg"
attExtract = ExtractByAttributes ('MG_2015_2017.tif', '"Value" = (2103,2109,1405,2103)'
attExtract.save ("D: \ pro-restore \ ProRestore-data \ outout-mg \ reproject-mg \ class_UpVeg.tif") `

Comment: I updated my answer. If you don't have Spatial Analyst, it will not work. You need to add this line `from arcpy.sa import *` if you have Spatial Analyst.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the where_clause variable. You should surround the clause with quotations.

```
where_clause = '"Value" = 2103'
```

Comment: Now I understand, mr.@Mohannad !
I'm really appreciate your help!
Unfortunately, I'm still stuck with a simple problem setting up my workspace.
I use `env.workspace = r 'D: / pro-restore / ProReset-data / ProReset'
And I get the message "Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)".
I tried to invert the bars in writing the path, but still the same error happens.

Comment: @Lilian I don't think that the problem is in this line. To be sure try to run it seperately preceded by "import arcpy" and "from arcpy import env".

Answer (score 0):

you can use this clause, for example,
attExtract = ExtractByAttributes("test_dem", "VALUE=500 OR value=1000 OR value=1500")